# Access javascript through Flash Player

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am trying to access a javascript function through flash player and the code is working for twitter. But in case of facebook, when i post the swf file and try to access the code, the flash player doesn't work. I think there is a problem of script access. But i have set the code:

```
allow script access to always
```

in the php file where i embedd the flash player. But in case of facebook i am unable to embedd my php file. So, is there any way by which i can set allow script access to my swf file in facebook??? Does facebook allows this or not?

Comment: That is not the problem actually when i want to post the swf player into my facebook account, then i have to provide source path of swf only that's why i am unable to append javascript along with it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually what i found in most cases is Facebook don't allow the "**script access always**" functionality to flash player due to security reasons. So, you must use a link to embed your flash player to get the functionality you want.

Hope it helps.